# gulp-eslint module work not as expected

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, eslint

I start to use the **gulp-eslint** module for checking js-files. Use es2015. But module can't find anything and always ends the same way.

```
:~$ gulp
[12:54:04] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/.../gulpfile.js
[12:54:04] Starting 'lint'...
[12:54:05] Finished 'lint' after 1.3 s
[12:54:05] Starting 'default'...
[12:54:05] Finished 'default' after 15 μs
```

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp'), eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', () =>
    gulp.src(['**/*.js','!node_modules/**'])
        .pipe(eslint({
            "parserOptions": {
                "ecmaVersion": 6,
                "sourceType": "module"
            },
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
);

gulp.task('default', ['lint']);
```

How use this module right? Or I need another module or way?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: not error, I show log

Comment: Is it possible there are no issues in your `.js` files.